# If I initialize argv to any other variable other than third, I get an error

Tags: python, python-2.7, argv

Here is the snippet from Zed A. Shaw's "Learning python the hard way". When I initialize a first or second variable to argv, I get an error. I haven't found an explanation to this.

```
from sys import argv
script, first, second, third=argv

print "the script is called:",script
print "your first variable is called ",first
print "your second variable is called ",second
print "your third variable is called ",third
```

Comment: How are you calling your script? That's important

Comment: I am calling it from the command line.

Comment: With what command?

Comment: >>python ex13.py a,b,c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use commas between arguments, you always need to give a space, otherwise the compiler thinks `1,2,3` is one argument, hence the error:

```
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

Call the script like this:

```
python ex13.py a, b, c
```

Answer (score 3):

Can I copy the error to see what error has occurred?

When I execute the above code, it runs normally.

**NOT USING COMMA**

Argv check with space.

```
$ python b.py 1 2 3  
the script is called: b.py
your first variable is called  1
your second variable is called  2
your third variable is called  3
```

**Versions**

```
 ⚡ root@dev # uname -a 
Linux dev 4.4.0-1031-aws #40-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 10 11:29:58 UTC 2017 x86_64 
x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
⚡ root@dev # cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS \n \l
⚡ root@dev # python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10)
```

Comment: try the below snippet. i am getting error as "name 'second' is not defined
"

from sys import argv
script, first=argv, second, third

print "the script is called:",script
print "your first variable is called ",first
print "your second variable is called ",second
print "your third variable is called ",third

Comment: @chaitanyaguruprasad What's your enviroment? I attached my versions

Comment: @chaitanyaguruprasad Execute command line on "python [YOURFILE] foo bar foo"

Comment: A small confusion, do you mean "can you" on our first line ? I understand that as you are asking OP to provide more details.

Comment: @chaitanyaguruprasad Your command is wrong with comma there is an error.

Comment: @SeonggwonYoon i tried removing the comma as well. Error is still there.

Comment: @chaitanyaguruprasad >> python ex13.py a b c

Comment: @chaitanyaguruprasad how about that?

Comment: @SeonggwonYoon 

C:\Users\chaitanya.prasad\PycharmProjects\ZedShaw>python ex13.py a b c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex13.py", line 2, in <module>
    script, first=argv, second, third
NameError: name 'second' is not defined

Comment: @chaitanyaguruprasad The code you run is different from what you show in your question. Can you tell?

Comment: @chaitanyaguruprasad Check your code. line 2 is script, first=argv, second, third... change to script, first, second, third=argv   your code is different

Comment: @SeonggwonYoon thats exactly my question.

the following works.
`from sys import argv
script, first, second, third=argv

print "the script is called:",script
print "your first variable is called ",first
print "your second variable is called ",second
print "your third variable is called ",third`

the following doesnt
`from sys import argv
script, first=argv, second, third

print "the script is called:",script
print "your first variable is called ",first
print "your second variable is called ",second
print "your third variable is called ",third`

please explain why

Comment: @chaitanyaguruprasad In the first code, you only connect first to argv and not to the remaining variables. The second code is followed by first, second, and thrid argv connections.

Comment: @SeonggwonYoon thanks. that was the answer i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing the third argument. You are unpacking argv. `a,b,c = argv` is like `a = argv[0]; b = argv[1]; c = argv[2];...`